# Jenkins, Mesos and slave dependencies

Tags: mesos, build-dependencies, mesosphere

**Background**
Our current infrastructure consists of a Jenkins master and a number of slave VM's. We are running into a lot of scalability and inherently stability issues with our tests as the VM's are being overworked.

**Mesosphere and Jenkins** 
That being said, I'm looking to explore more solutions, particularly with mesosphere because its ability to dynamically generate slaves as needed.

My only issue with that is that we have all these dependencies installed on the slave VM's. In order to make Jenkins work on mesos, I would have to "dirty" the mesos slaves by installing the dependencies on them. This would kind of render these mesos slaves useless as they would only be suited for running Jenkins.

**Question** 
What is the proper method of implementing a Jenkins environment in Mesos alongside other applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out eBay's video and blogs about their Mesos+Marathon+Jenkins setup:

- http://blog.docker.com/2014/06/dockercon-video-delivering-ebays-ci-solution-with-apache-mesos-docker/
- http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2014/04/04/delivering-ebays-ci-solution-with-apache-mesos-part-i/
- http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2014/05/12/delivering-ebays-ci-solution-with-apache-mesos-part-ii/

Part II of the blog talks about running Jenkins builds in Docker containers, which could alleviate the problem of "dirtying" the slaves with dependencies.

See the mesos-jenkins plugin for more documentation, and see dockerhub for pre-built images

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin
- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/folsomlabs/jenkins-mesos/ (latest)
- https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/thefactory/jenkins-mesos/ (documented)

Comment: This is actually the clarification I was looking for. It seems more of these distributed systems rely on the containerization of such applications, in this case Docker. Thanks!